# DESIGN Как сохранить иконки svg? Файлом .svg или html кодом <svg>

Tags: css, html5, svg, icon, design

В макете есть иконки, сам сервис мне предлагает svg код. Как мне лучше сделать для верстки страницы? Сохранять файлами в формате .svg или же все таки кодом? 
Суть вопроса как будет лучше вообще
P.S При наведении на иконку он должен менять цвет. (сервис Figma)

Comment: ксли свг будет файлом, то цвет его элементов менять будет проблематичнее

Comment: ну или как object можно подключать - тогда все анимации и смена цвета сохранится

Comment: В файле `.svg` находится сам код svg элемента, его можно использовать в html.